# Phonegrap stalling on "trying to install app onto emulator"

Tags: android, android-emulator, cordova

I installed phonegap CLI on my Mac OSX 10.7.5 and used it to create the default "Hello World" app.  I then issue the command `phonegrap run android -emulator`.  This runs through the steps and then stalls at the point of `"trying to install app onto emulator."`  The Emulator loads and is running as normal and I can navigate the emulator perfectly fine but the terminal just stalls and never actually installs the phonegap application.  Anyone ran into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I ran into the same issue but on Ubuntu android emulator. The emulator started fine but the application actually not installed. I don't know why it happened. I googled around and someone said it might caused by the project name, you couldn't use space and dash in the project name. But it just doesn't work for me.